# Appendix pages placement and layout

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices

I use `\chapter{Appendix I}` to create an Appendix I title however it appears as shown below:

[image]

Then I use  `\chapter*{Appendix I}` to remove the Chapter 10 part but when I do that the Appendix I no longer appears in the Table of Contents section.

What should I do to achieve an Appendix page that appears both in the table of contents and also doesnt have a Chapter X with it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may depend on the document class that you are using, but the usual way is to use `\appendix`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\appendix
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} %New
\chapter{An appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks nice. Is it possible to do it Appendix I instead of Appendix A ?

Comment: @Cemre --- indeed it is. I have edited my answer.